# Railscast geocoding missing JSON::ParserError constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, railscasts

Replicating the geocoding example from Railscast #273 at http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder
under Rails 3.1rc4 using:

```
    multi_json (1.0.3)
   nifty-generators (0.4.6)
```

I get

```
NameError in LocationsController#create

uninitialized constant JSON::ParserError
Rails.root: ...

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:20:in `create'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   multi_json/engines/json_gem
```

I must be missing something which defines this.  Anyone have an idea?rc4

Comment: Hmmm.  Got it working, by adding explicit:

    gem 'json_pure'
    gem 'json'

to Gemfile.

Why is that necessary, given that mutil_json has these in its own dependencies?

Comment: I get the same error with a vanilla 3.1.0.rc5 new app, so it likely is an error in the release candidates and not something specific to the geocoding app. Also, your fix worked for me, too.